# can I read public static final field inside a nested public static abstract class in Java

Tags: java, android, oop, android-sqlite, abstract-class

So a while back I created a SQLiteHelper Class in my Android App.  I'm not 100% certain why, but the table and column names were public static final fields in a nested public static abstract class.  As I recall, the goal was to protect the fields from being modified.  It all works great but things are starting to get sophisticated with my app and I want to populate fields in other classes with the public static final table and column name fields.  After some trial and error, and reading about abstract classes, static classes, and nesting classes, it occurred to me that can just call the field directly, as in.

```
String myTable = MySQLiteHelper.dbFields.TABLE_NAME_REMINDER;
```

Even though I've read up on these topics, how it all comes together in my specific case is still making me scratch my head.  So my question is, since the fields are static final, does nesting the fields actually provide additional protection, and if the nested class is static, why also make it abstract?  Is static AND abstract required to call it directly without needing to instantiate the outer and nested classes?

Thanks for the help.  I'm really trying to get my head wrapped around the various class implementations.

Here's the key elements of the class :

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Reminders.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    public int DatabaseVersion = DATABASE_VERSION;

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static abstract class dbFields implements BaseColumns {

        //dbFields Table Fields
        public static final String TABLE_NAME_REMINDER = "reminders";
        public static final String COLUMN_REMINDER_ID = _ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_REMINDER = "reminder";
        public static final String COLUMN_REMINDER_ALTITUDE = "altitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_REMINDER_USED = "is_used";
        public static final String COLUMN_REMINDER_LASTUSED = "last_used";
        public static final String COLUMN_REMINDER_ACTION = "action";
        public static final String COLUMN_REMINDER_SCORE = "score";
        public static final String COLUMN_REMINDER_RELATIONSHIP = "relationship";

        //Special_Days Table Fields
        public static final String TABLE_NAME_SPECIAL_DAYS = "special_days";
        public static final String COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ID = _ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_DATE = "date";  //dbDataRow strField 1
        public static final String COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_NAME = "name"; //dbDataRow dbData
        public static final String COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ALTITUDE = "altitude"; //dbDataRow intField 1
        public static final String COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_USED = "is_used"; //dbDataRow Field 2
        public static final String COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_WARNING = "warning"; //dbDataRow intField 3
        public static final String COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ACTION = "action"; //dbDataRow intField 4
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since the fields are static final, does nesting the fields actually provide additional protection

No, it doesn't. As you've seen, you can access the fields even if they're nested and, since they're static and final, you can't modify them.

> and if the nested class is static, why also make it abstract? Is static AND abstract required to call it directly without needing to instantiate the outer and nested classes?

The purpose of abstract is to allow you to have a base class that has a method with no implementation. One classic example is an Animal class. All animals make a noise (probably not, but let's pretend) so the Animal class should have a `makeNoise` method. But, every animals noise is different so it doesn't make sense to have any implementation in the base class. The `Cat` subclass might look like `public String makeNoise() { return "meow"; }` and the `Dog` subclass might return "woof", but there's no sane implementation of `makeNoise` on the base class. However, if you didn't have any `makeNoise` on the base class you couldn't ask an arbitrary animal to `makeNoise`. So you'd have a `public abstract String makeNoise()` method on the base. That lets you call `makeNoise` for any animal even if all you have is a reference to an `Animal`.

Note that abstract has nothing to do with the class being nested or not. Other classes, nested or not, can inherit from a nested static class. It also has nothing to do with hiding data or otherwise protecting data or code.

So, to answer your question: you should make it abstract if and only if the purpose of being abstract applies here. Given your sample code, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

> since the fields are static final, does nesting the fields actually provide additional protection

Not if the nested class is public: it just provides a notational inconvenience.

> and if the nested class is static, why also make it abstract?

No idea, it's your class.

> Is static AND abstract required to call it directly without needing to instantiate the outer and nested classes?

No, `static` is sufficient.

I don't see any need for the `BaseColumns` interface here either. I would look seriously at using an `Enum` for the column names.

Comment: It wasn't totally my code.  It was derived from a sample for a website about Android databases.  All my questions were related to how the sample was organized, and my confusion regarding the sample was the reason for the question.

Comment: Well it's certainly not *my* code, and I'm certainly not able to answer questions about why the author used `abstract,` whoever he was. Nor is anybody else.

Comment: Yes, I see now that it doesn't appear to make sense.  So in that sense, you answered the question.